# trouble selecting the first child of nested elements

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the first line item (`<li>`) with the class "subnav".

I just cannot seem to get it:

html:

```
<nav>
<ul class="navigation">

 <li class="logo"><ul>
    <li><a href="index.htm"><img src="images/rh_logo_v5.png" alt="roundhaus logo"/></a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="subnav"><ul>
    <li><a href="index.htm">home</a></li>
   </ul></li>
<li class="subnav"><ul>
    <li><a href="reclaimedwood.htm">reclaimed wood</a></li>
       <li><a href="design.htm">design</a></li>
   </ul></li>
  <li class="subnav"><ul>
    <li><a href="flooring.htm">flooring</a></li>
    <li><a href="paneling.htm">paneling</a></li>
    <li><a href="beams.htm">beams</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="subnav"><ul>
    <li><a href="shelving.htm">shelving</a>
    </li><li><a href="mantels.htm">mantels</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="subnav"><ul>
    <li><a href="news.htm">news</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="subnav"><ul>
    <li><a href="woodtypes.htm">wood types</a></li>
    <li><a href="phrases.htm">phrases</a></li>
</ul></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

What would be the CSS selector be for the first instance of the line item with the class "subnav"?

Comment: `li` stands for *list* item, not *line* item :)

Comment: are you trying to select <li><a href="index.htm">home</a></li> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first `.subnav` item starts right after a single `.logo` item, you can use

```
li.logo:first-child + li.subnav
```

Notice that the `:first-child` in your markup is actually `.logo`, and not one of the `.subnav` items. If you were trying to use `li.subnav:first-child`, that's the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks, that has worked. As a novice it seems a tricky one to remember - I'm not sure if I could replicate that method in the future because I don't get the logic of having to select the logo first? Surely there must be a way to select the first child based upon class?

Comment: @Doug Firr: Unfortunately CSS doesn't provide a selector for matching the first child with a class. I came up with a somewhat verbose yet versatile trick that involves an overriding rule, which you can see in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/106224), but your structure allows for a simpler approach which I went with here. There's a note about the possibility of allowing this with CSS4 selectors in that answer as well, but that's for the somewhat distant future...

Comment: so no first child selector based on class for now - thanks for the info. You really helped me out with that selector too

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
"li.subnav:first"
```

If you are using jQuery, then you can get first subnav with:

```
$("li.subnav:first")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You **have** to use jQuery or some other selector library with this. `:first` isn't a CSS selector.